# How to execute MainApp.java program using Swings?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem in executing program when i click on Jbutton named GetSummary. I want the MainApp.java file to be executed when i click on the button names GetSumamry. Can someone please tell me what code should i write in actionPerformed function to run this program ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a main-Method has the signature

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

you call it like every other static method:

```
String [] dummy = new String [0] ();
```

if you don't have arguments, an empty array,

```
MainApp.main (dummy);
```

returns void, so no assignment, and called by the class, not with a reference (new MainApp.main).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile `MainApp.java`first. Then:

```
String[] cmd = {"java", "MainApp"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

if you want to wait for the process to finish:

```
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: You have to handle an IOException, and if you use p.waitFor an InterruptedException, and handle the usual pitfalls of Runtime.getRuntime http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html? . In some cases, you might need exactly that, including the JVM with its own ClassLoader (some Singletons will not be that single therefore), but in most cases you don't need an second JVM.

Comment: I omitted exception handling for clarity, IDE will generate the code for that anyway. I understood that OP wants to spawn a separate process not just execute a method.

Comment: A new, non-blocking program can be started with the main-method, but is running in the same JVM. This saves memory since it shares resources with interesting consequences for the singleton pattern and naive usage of `System.exit`, which terminates both programs, if no counter-methods are taken. (If source available: `setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` instead of EXIT).